# How to distinguish between different causes of app termination in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, confirmation, termination, quit

I would like my application to ask for confirmation before quitting, *except* when it's being terminated by the system during shutdown or restart (because when OS X tries to apply security updates at midnight it gets stuck on the "Are you sure?" message box).

How can I find what initiated the termination? In `[NSApp terminate:sender]` the sender is always `nil`.

My first thought was to ask only when the "Quit" main menu item is activated, but the user can also terminate application from the Dock menu or by pressing Cmd+Q while holding Cmd+Tab, and I'd like to ask for confirmation in these cases as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a notification when the system is about to power off, restart, or if the user just logs out. This is not an ordinary notification, but a workspace notification.

You can register for the notification like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    //...more code...

    self.powerOffRequestDate = [NSDate distantPast];
    NSNotificationCenter *wsnCenter = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];
    [wsnCenter addObserver:self
                  selector:@selector(workspaceWillPowerOff:)
                      name:NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification
                    object:nil];
}
```

in the notification handler, you should just save away the date:

```
- (void)workspaceWillPowerOff:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.powerOffRequestDate = [NSDate new];
}
```

Add

```
@property (atomic,strong,readwrite) NSDate *powerOffRequestDate;
```

to the appropriate place.

when your app is asked to terminate, you should get that date and check if the computer is about to shut off.

```
if([self.powerOffRequestDate timeIntervalSinceNow] > -60*5) {
    // shutdown immediately
} else {
    // ask user
}
```

I chose an intervall of 5minutes for the following edge case: The computer should power off, but another app cancels that. Your app is still running. 10min later, the user closes your app. In that case, the app *should* ask the user. This is a bit of a hack, but it's not a "crazy hack" I think...

Hope this helps.